# How to write rspec test for api wrapper model in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a ruby on rails newbie. I read up on testing using webmock, creating stub request/response in rspec and working through it.below in the test method, do I need to create a new instance of the client class?  and do I make a call to my send_request method. does it actually make a call to my model , if I do subject.send_request in rspec? , do I assign the return value to something to test?

rspec file

```
describe Api::Client do 
  describe 'it sends a request' do 
   subject {Api::Client.new}
   stub_request(:get, 'https://api.twitter.com').to_return(status : 200 , body : {})

   #how to write expect statement here 
  end
end
```

class file

```
module Api
    class Client
      API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.twitter.com'

      def client
        @_client ||= Faraday.new(API_ENDPOINT) 
      end

      def send_request
       client.public_send('Get', API_ENDPOINT)
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: If you stubbed the request correctly, then calling `send_request` in rspec would not actually talk to the API

Comment: @maxpleaner - thanks. that's where I having problem. isn't the stub_request correct? In all the example, i saw they have this construct. given stub_request is correct, do i simply call  subject.send_request and that will give me stubbed response?

Comment: @maxpleaner - how can I check , if the stub_request is even being loaded or called, or webmock is enabled or working? is there a way I can print or save to a file,  the request from my stub_request method?

Comment: Just tell Webmock to disable all actual HTTP requests, then any request that goes through will raise an error.

Comment: @maxpleaner - thanks. looks like we can stub/mock in rspec without using webmock. doing something like this - allow(obj).to receive(:message).and_return(:value). where , we mimic a call, does it actually test our code. does it actually calls the method in my actual class, and only the return value is pre-defined and we are actually executing and testing code?

Comment: When you call "allow..to receive..and return" the method is NOT actually run. You would have to add "and_call_original" to actually run it. And by the way, to REQUIRE that the method was called, rather than simply ALLOW it, use "expect" instead of "allow"